# In Flutter, how to do a row layout with textfield and a square image

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

Im trying to achieve the following layout **inside a row** (please see attached image):

1. A TextField, with 3 lines
2. A square image container (aspect ratio of 1:1), where the image has a cover fit

[image]

Constraints:
I want the TextField to set the height of the row, so no matter how big or small the font size, the image will always be square, and its height the same as the TextField height.
So I **don't want to use any pixel sizes**

This is my initial code, but of course the image is not constrained...
Any ideas on how to fix that?

```
IntrinsicHeight(
  child: Row(
    children: [
      Flexible(
        child: TextField(
          controller: _controller,
          maxLines: 3,
        ),
      ),
      Image.file(File(imagePath), fit: BoxFit.cover)
    ],
  ),
)
```

Comment: looks like a job for `IntrinsicHeight`

Comment: there is an IntrinsicHeight there...

Comment: ooops, did not see it :-(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
IntrinsicHeight(
      child: Row(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        children: [
          Flexible(
            child: TextField(
              controller: _controller,
              maxLines: 3,
            ),
          ),
          AspectRatio(
            aspectRatio: 1,
            child: Image.file(File(imagePath), fit: BoxFit.cover, width: 0),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
```

Comment: didn't work for me. The image (a large one) wants to fill as much space as possible...

Comment: Do u mean when the image is too big, it must resize smaller to only fit height of 3 text row ?

Comment: Correct. the height of the row should always be 3 lines of text, and the image size (rectangular) should adjust to that

Comment: Okay check my update answer, it need to add width 0 property

Comment: WOW, that works! what kind of black magic is it (width: 0)?

Comment: Haha yes black magic even I don't know, it work so let it be xD

Answer (score 2):

In this case you need to have `TextField` height, so you can get that with `GlobalKey` like this:

```
class TestingDesign2 extends StatefulWidget {
  const TestingDesign2({super.key});

  @override
  State<TestingDesign2> createState() => _TestingDesign2State();
}

class _TestingDesign2State extends State<TestingDesign2> {
  GlobalKey textKey = GlobalKey();
  double textHeight = 0.0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      setState(() {
        final textKeyContext = textKey.currentContext;
        if (textKeyContext != null) {
          final box = textKeyContext.findRenderObject() as RenderBox;
          textHeight = box.size.height;
        }
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Row(
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child: TextField(
                  key: textKey,
                  controller: TextEditingController(),
                  maxLines: 3,
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: textHeight,
                child: AspectRatio(
                  aspectRatio: 1,
                  child:
                      Image.asset('assets/images/test.jpeg', fit: BoxFit.cover),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]